# CSS post processor to split file in half

Tags: html, css, gruntjs, build-tools

I have a large CSS file in my website, and would like to split it in two equal parts so that it can load in parallel and let the page render earlier. Seems to work ok when I cut the file in half by hand, but I would like to be able to do it as part of my build process.

Is there any tool to split a css file in half?

I have found similar tools, but not exactly what I need... http://cssnano.co, https://github.com/postcss/postcss and https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-split-styles (the last of which is almost perfect, but how to find the centre point..?)

---

EDIT: first effort...

Having not found anything that exactly fits my requirement, I went about trying to adapt something that is close, with one small change to https://github.com/project-collins/grunt-csssplit ...

```
diff --git a/lib/splitter.js b/lib/splitter.js
index 81d427c..041cf77 100644
--- a/lib/splitter.js
+++ b/lib/splitter.js
@@ -82,8 +82,9 @@ Splitter.prototype._toPages = function (ast, maxSelectors) {
     pages.push(clone);

     var selectorsForThisPage = 0;
-    ast.stylesheet.rules.forEach(function (rule) {
-        if (selectorsForThisPage + rule.totalSelectors <= maxSelectors) {
+
+    ast.stylesheet.rules.forEach(function (rule, i) {
+        if (Math.round(ast.stylesheet.rules.length/2) !== i) {
             selectorsForThisPage += rule.totalSelectors;
             clone.stylesheet.rules.push(rule);
         }
```

I am able to split my original css file in two by putting half the rules in part one and half in part two...

```
➜  grunt-csssplit git:(master) ✗ grunt csssplit && ls -ltrah
Running "csssplit:your_target" (csssplit) task
File "dest_part_1" created.
File "dest_part_2" created.

Done, without errors.
...
-rw-r--r--   1 moon  staff    96K  6 Oct 09:28 dest_part_2
-rw-r--r--   1 moon  staff    98K  6 Oct 09:28 dest_part_1
➜  grunt-csssplit git:(master) ✗ gzip dest_part_*
➜  grunt-csssplit git:(master) ✗ ls -ltrah
...
-rw-r--r--   1 moon  staff    12K  5 Oct 16:56 dest_part_1.gz
-rw-r--r--   1 moon  staff    18K  6 Oct 09:28 dest_part_2.gz
➜  grunt-csssplit git:(master) ✗
```

Before gzip the file sizes are similar, but after zipping, there is a significant difference between part one and two. I really need the two parts to be fairly equal in size after gzip so that it balances the network traffic.

1. How can I go about splitting css file into equal parts **after** gzip?
2. I feel like I am probably going about this all wrong - is there a better way?
3. Splitting my css file in half gets text readable on screen 50% faster, which seems to work great. Are there any drawbacks to splitting for the sake of loading in parallel? Most information on the internet points at combining css files to reduce network requests.

Comment: C'mon, with 27K+ rep you *have* to know that asking for a tool recommendation is off-topic. "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: It's really a performance tooling question I tried to help answer. Hope this helps you Billy.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for performance gains, don't mess with manually splitting your CSS file at all. What you have seen about having the fewest HTTP requests for performance reasons is true.

What you really want to do is identify your critical path CSS ([check this CSS Tricks article out](https://css-tricks.com/authoring-critical-fold-css/) for a background) and inline it to load ahead of the rest of your page's CSS.

The [grunt critical](https://github.com/bezoerb/grunt-critical) plugin attempts to do just that. This is the example grunt task you'd have to include:

```
critical: {
    test: {
        options: {
            base: './',
            css: [
                'test/fixture/styles/main.css',
                'test/fixture/styles/bootstrap.css'
            ],
            width: 320,
            height: 70
        },
        src: 'test/fixture/index.html',
        dest: 'test/generated/index-critical.html'
    }
}
```

This utility is extra cool - if you define the `dest` file as an HTML, it will automatically create the inline CSS for you and put it in the corresponding file.

Another option to consider is the [Critical Node.js plugin](https://github.com/addyosmani/critical) if you're trying to do this on a node project.

Comment: This is great, but I would really like to validate why fewer HTTP requests is always better, because the numbers I am seeing tell a different story in this very specific case. The premise of my idea is that browsers now tend to have 6 or more concurrent connections, even on mobile devices, and if I use the first six connections for my critical assets (one for html, four for css and one for js) then they load faster, and content is rendered on screen faster leaving non critical assets (images and more js etc...) to load afterwards.

Comment: By merging all css into one file, the available bandwidth is shared between critical and non-critical assets, delaying the rendering of content. Full page load time remains constant.

Comment: I will ask another question about this separately.

Comment: Billy - glad it was helpful. Watch this presentation on the TCP handshake by Paul Irish - fantastic stuff: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R8W_6xWphtw